# I have a problem with slash in javaScript n Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, slash

I have a problem with slash in javaScript n Ajax

I am displaying value dynamically in a span like below:

```
String num = "37-C110PDD/L";

<span id="p21stk_<%=NUM%>"></span>
```

in Script:

value for  chks[0] is  `37-C110PDD/L` here the value contains slash and is not displaying the required value in span

Code used in script to update value dynamically:

```
$("#p21stkArwhed_"+chks[0].value).html($("#qohArrVal_"+chks[0].value).val())
```

Above code working for parameters without SLASH

Any idea how to solve....?

Thank you..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using slashes in the attribute ID is illegal.
See [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

You should replace your slash with a valid character, an hyphen ("-") or an underscore ("_") for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom data-* attributes (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes), for example:

HTML:

```
<span data-id="37-C110PDD/L">a span</span>
```

JS:

```
alert( $("span[data-id='37-C110PDD/L']").text() );
```